# Group several table columns and overflow to left

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I want to display a kind of competitions results table. Each row has a participant name, followed by several cells representing participant results in last competitions (say, the competitions take place once per week). Something like this:

```
User name    Aug 1   Aug 8   Aug 15
John Doe       1       10     100
Jane Doe      100      10      1
```

The table may become very wide if many columns are present. In such a case, I want the oldest columns to be hidden, so that only a few most recent are visible, and the table does not overflow the available space. The user name columns should always be visible.

The "borderline" cells can be "cut" like this:

```
User name    g 1   Aug 8   Aug 15
John Doe     1       10     100
Jane Doe     00      10      1
```

...or they can be completely invisible, both variants are acceptable to me.

**It is possible to achieve this with pure css?**

---

For just one line, I've achieved it without a `table`, using `display: flex` together with `direction: rtl` for the 'columns' only:

https://jsfiddle.net/fo2Ldk3n/

```css
.outer {
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-right;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.header {
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.line-box {
  direction: rtl;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.line {
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: inline;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="header">
    User Name
  </div>
  <div class="line-box">
    <div class="line">
      2223 +1
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      10
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      100
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      10
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      100
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      10
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      100
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

However, this obviously fails for several rows, because the numbers will not be aligned into columns:

[image]

I've tried to use `colgroup` and set `display: rtl` etc. for the results `col`, but it would not work.

---

Also note that `direction: rtl` results in wrong order of 'words' within a cell (see 1+ 2223, which should be 2223 +1). The latter is not really a big problem, as I will mostly have only numbers in the cells, so it's ok if the solution has this problem. But it'll be better if it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it. The key is to use table wrapped into `div` with `direction: rtl`, this gives cells going from right to left and overflowing to the left. And use `position: absolute` for user names.

An additional `direction: ltr` on `td` even makes cell content render in correct direction.

```css
.outer {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  direction: rtl;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.row td {
  direction: ltr;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <table class="table">
    <tr class="row">
      <td>1 + 100</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td class="header">User name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td class="header">Long long user name</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[image]

The user name cells have different widths, but this seems to me.